# Ring of p-adic integers and harmonic sums

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am trying to understand p-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and want to ask two questions:

1. For a fixed rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ and a prime $p$, I can write $p$-adic expansion of the fraction after some calculations, most of the time.(For example $\cfrac{2}{5}  \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ since it is equal to $1+3+2.3^2+3^3+\dots \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ ). However, I do not know a general algorithm. So, my question is, for any odd number  $n$, how can I show that $\cfrac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}_2?$
2. What is the structure of $p^k \mathbb{Z}_p$ for some positive integer $k$? Is it the ring of power series $\displaystyle p^k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n p^n = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n p^n?$

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of sequences $(a_k)$ such that $a_k \in \Bbb{Z/p^k Z}$ and $a_k \equiv a_m \bmod p^m$ ($m \le k$), a ring with the pointwise addition and multiplication $\bmod p^k$. Thus $1/n$ is the sequence of inverses of $n$ modulo $p^k$. Show this is equivalent to $p$-adic series. The case $p=2$ and $n$ odd : then $n - 1 \equiv 0 \bmod 2$ so $\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (n-1)^k$.

Comment: The question could also be considered a "baby" version of a typical Hensel's lemma problem.  The idea is that once you have a solution to $bx_0 \equiv a \pmod{p}$, you can then use a procedure that formally looks like Newton's method to iteratively refine $x_0$ into a solution to $bx = a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @reuns, what is $m$?

Comment: What @reuns has written should hold true for all naturals m < k. Often, these sequences are constructed such that $a_k \equiv a_{k-1} \mod p^{k-1}$ for all k, which ensures that it is true for all m < k. 

about your second question, what you have there looks correct. Interesting to note that we can define the ring of p-adic numbers as $Q_p = \bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty} p^{-j} \mathbb{Z}_p = \left \{ \sum_{j = -N}^{\infty} a_j p^j \hspace{2pt} | \hspace{2pt} N \in \mathbb{N}, 0 \leq a_j < p \right \}$

Answer (score 0):

1. To show a number exists as a p-adic integer, we can write it as an equation and check Hensel's lemma. Hensel's lemma is essentially a canned induction argument waiting for you to confirm the base case and that a necessary step for lifting is satisfied. To do this we have to check that:

$$f(x) \equiv 0 \mod p$$
$$f'(x) \not \equiv 0 \mod p$$

So, for your choice you want to show $x=\frac{a}{b}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then all we need to do is rearrange it into $$f(x) = bx-a = 0$$ and check the two above conditions.

There is more to say, since just failing to satisfy those conditions doesn't necessarily mean it's not a p-adic integer. It's probably best to check out the proof for Hensel's lemma to get a better understanding since that itself shows from those two starting conditions how to construct the base p expansion of a p-adic integer.

2. It's nearly the ring of formal power series but there's an important difference, we keep the $a_i$ to be from a distinct residue set; a common choice is $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$. When we add the two p-adic numbers we are forced to "carry" which doesn't happen if we treat the powers $p^n$ as distinct. 
   This is not the only choice either, there are the Teichmuller characters which satisfy $\omega^{p-1} = 1$ that can also be used as "digits" of a p-adic number. To add and multiply them in this form the analogue for "carrying" is a different procedure and is described by Witt vectors.